# Any ideas on how to avoid class constructor property drilling for vanilla JS?

Tags: typescript, class, composition

I am having a bit of a problem with composition in my library that I am developing, and I am curious what people think about how I go about it.

It all starts at the entrypoint of the app, the `Client` class. The user who consumes the package will instatiate it, or potentially many.

My idea was that the instance of the class will hold its own local "singletons", an example of a useful singleton is the Rest class instance which contains authorisation information and should be the same throughout the lifetime of the `Client` instance and be reused for sub-classes for authenticated requests.

```
// Rest.ts
export default class Rest {
    #authorisation?: string;

    login() {
        //...
    }

    logout() {
        //...
    }

    fetch() {
        // fetch api
    }
}

// Client.ts
export default class Client {
    rest = new Rest();

    fetchApiResponse(): APIResponse {
        const response = await this.rest.fetch("something.com");
        const json = await response.json();

        return new APIResponse(json, this);
    }
}

// ChildClass.ts
export default class APIResponse {
    constructor(data: unknown, client: Client) {
        this.something = data.something;

        this.#client = client;
    }

    something: unknown;

    #client: Client;

    fetchAuthorisedAPIData(): AnotherInstance {
        return this.client.rest.fetch("somethingonlyauthuserscansee.com", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                key: this.something,
            }),
        });

        //... more code here
        // Pretend there's another class instance I might return that needs the client too
    }
}
```

This `Client` class contains methods that reach out to an API, and return more class instances created from the API response. These class instances then have helpful methods that work around the response from the API.

However, the only way the subclasses can access the rest instance is with constructor property drilling, so when I create a new instance, I pass in an instance of the client to the constructor so it has access to the `Rest` class.

In my library, there are three layers of classes, and sometimes the class in the middle acts more of a messenger, passing the instance through from the parent to the child constructor.

I don't want to keep passing the client through layers of classes just to get an authorised fetch.

Any ideas on a good pattern to overcome this composition problem?

Comment: I probably wont make an answer as this isn't so comprehensive. But why not just use regular objects and functions rather than classes and class methods. Generally solves a lot of these problems.